# Querying a SQL Table using conditions from another table

Tags: sql, join

Stuck on SQL college question!

I want to search the table `Em_Sum` and find any `Em_num` that went from column `Em_before` (4, 5, 6) to `Em_after` (6), but I only want to query `Employees` who have the `type_id` 1, 2 or 3 which can be seen in table `Em_Type`.

This is what I have so far

```
SELECT Em_Sum.Em_num
FROM Em_Sum
FULL JOIN Em_Type ON Em_Type.Em_num = Em_Sum.Em_num
WHERE Em_Type.Type_id IN (1, 2, 3) 
  AND Em_Sum.Em_before IN (4, 5, 6) 
  AND Em_Sum.Em_after IN (6) ;
```

I'm just confused as to how to query the `Em_Type` table using `Type_id`

Comment: And what is wrong with you current query? `FULL JOIN` with `IN` conditions on fields from both the tables effectively is an `INNER JOIN`. Also using `JOIN` you should be sure that `Em_Type` table has no duplicates in `Em_Num` column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good thing you've tried to find the answer yourself. I think what you did is correct.
First you indeed join the 2 tables. Next you can filter on either table you want.

e.g.:

```
SELECT sum.Em_num
  FROM Em_Sum sum  --we are giving this table an alias 'sum'
  JOIN Em_Type type  --this table gets alias 'type'
--now join both tables on the primary/foreign key 'employee number (=Em_num)':
    ON type .Em_num = Em_Sum.Em_num    
 WHERE type.Type_id IN (1, 2, 3) 
   AND sum.Em_before IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) 
   AND sum.Em_after IN (1, 2, 3) ;
```

Comment: Thanks for reaching out. Sorry this might be a silly question but why do i need an alias?

Comment: Technically you do not need it, but it makes querying a lot easier, as it makes the code more readable. So it is not a requirement and you can leave it out. But it is a good coding standard to use it.

Comment: OK great! Thanks, this has been very helpful

Comment: You're welcome - please set this as the accepted answer to close this question. 
And welcome to the StackOverflow community.